# Why is the init method for the child class also altering the parent class?

Tags: python, marshmallow

Python version: 3.8.5

Marshmallow: 3.9.1

I created a method to create a Marshmallow schema and add attribute tags to whatever schema was passed into the function. You may see the example code below:

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

def _configure_y_subschema(schema):
    """Configures a Y schema wherever Y attributes are necessary.
    Args:
        schema: The ownership schema to duplicate
    Returns:
        A `YSchema` that is a duplication of the specified schema
        with all fields having `x_is_y = True`
    """
    y_dynamic_class = type(
        schema.__name__.replace('Schema', 'YSchema'),
        (schema,),
        {}
    )

    def y_init(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(y_dynamic_class, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].metadata['x_is_y'] = True

    y_dynamic_class.__init__ = y_init
    return y_dynamic_class


class SomeSchema(Schema):
   example1 = fields.String()
   example2 = fields.List(fields.Integer())


parent_schema_obj = SomeSchema()

child_y_schema_class = _configure_y_subschema(SomeSchema)
child_schema_obj = child_y_schema_class()
```

When I run the resulting code, all the fields in both the `parent_schema_obj`'s and the `child_schema_obj`'s fields have `x_is_y=True`. Does anyone know why both the parent and child are being updated? And if so, how can I have it be that only the child class has `x_is_y=True` attributes for its fields? Happy to provide any additional information.

Comment: Where is the definition of `Schema`? And for that matter, where is the definition of `fields`?

Comment: `fields` and `Schema` come from the marshmallow library @Grismar

Comment: Perhaps add an `from marshmallow import Schema, fields` statement to the start of the example and specify what version of Python and the library you're using?

Comment: Python version: 3.8.5 Marshmallow: 3.9.1 @Grismar

Comment: Is it because your original class is defining stuff as class variables?

Comment: Are you suggesting that there is a fundamental reason why the \_\_init__ method for a child class shouldn't modify the parent? I can't think why that would be the case.

Comment: @Steve not sure I follow but I do not intend for the child class to modify the parent

Answer (score 1):

You'll find that, in `y_init`, this conditions holds:

```
self.fields['example1'].metadata is parent_schema_obj.fields['example1'].metadata
```

The metadata dictionary for `child_y_schema_class` fields and `SomeSchema` fields is the same dictionary and when you modify it through `self.fields[field].metadata['x_is_y'] = True`, as a result you're modifying both.

It's unclear what you're trying to achieve, so it's hard to provide guidance on what to do differently. But this answers the 'why' question.

Comment: thanks for the info here @grismar. I am trying to have it so that only the child has `x_is_y=True`

Comment: That's a bit of an XY problem situation though - can you elaborate on why you're trying to achieve that? What's the goal here?

Comment: I have several schemas throughout my app and this is a small snippet. but imagine SomeSchema is nested inside of Schema, SchemaA, SchemaB, and SchemaC. In the schemas that end in A,B,C I need SomeSchema to have the attribute `x_is_y=True` but not in Schema. Instead of declaring the same SomeSchema in many places,  I just want a function to dynamically create a new class with the desired attributes @grismar

Comment: Wouldn't writing a mixin be the right approach to achieve that?

Comment: I'm struggling to see how a mixin would be able to change the attributes of a schema's fields? it would only contain a template for specific fields

Comment: It's still unclear why you'd need `SomeSchema` to "to have the attribute `x_is_y=True`". You could use a mixin to add in an identifying attribute, with some value - but it's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve by differentiating this attribute. Without knowing what you're trying to achieve (and why), it's impossible to provide an answer that actually helps.